# Dropdownlist restrict selectable values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a number of dropdownlists in a form, all of which are filled with the same `Taskid`'s from a database table.

Now when I have selected a certain value in any dropdownlist, this value should not be displayed in any of the other dropdownlists.

Comment: Please keep it to one question: [Selected value Validation in dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314331/selected-value-validation-in-dropdown-list). That one will not be reopened until you show what you have tried. Edit - oh, upvotes. Why?

Comment: For every dropdown list but the selected one search for the task ID in the collection called "Items" and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have some validation so that when the user submits, it can check for matching items across the dropdown lists.

Or you need to look into using the `.selectedIndexChanged` event:

Sample: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd7hsyy(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd7hsyy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you place some logic in this event, you can remove items / deselect items in other lists when an item is selected in each list. This could get complicated if you remove items though as you will have to rebind every time selections change and postback each time a selection is made.

I'd go with option 1: validation checks based on the details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) sender;
    IEnumerable<ListItem> selectedTasks = ddl.Items
        .Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Selected);

    foreach(ListItem item in selectedTasks)
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Remove(item);
        DropDownList3.Items.Remove(item);
        DropDownList4.Items.Remove(item);
        DropDownList5.Items.Remove(item);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Next question: _"When user first selects A and then B in list 1, none of the other lists show A or B anymore"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster: What is the question? If he wants to "reset" the dropdownlists he need to provide a button ("reload" or "cancel") and implement the appropriate logic.